# Bootstrap 3 - item float right in navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my current navigation:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ApplicationName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-navigation">
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

With this navigation I'm having this:
[image]

What I actually want is this:
[image]

I've tried floating of the anchor tag but it's floating just inside the li tag. In ExtJS I'm having the '->' item which provides me this behavior. How can I do this?

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add the `pull-right` class to the ul tag

Full Example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ApplicationName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-navigation">
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" id="main-navigation">
                <li><a href="#" class="pull-right">Item2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Result:
[image: works!]

Comment: Per Bootstrap's navbar docs, you should use `navbar-right` instead of `pull-right`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the element this:

CSS

```
li.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ApplicationName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li class="right"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/117425)

Comment: +1 for a different solution but I think the one from @Curtis W is more elegant or "Bootstrapper" solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

as of the new bootstrap, we dont use pull-right

As of v3.1.0, we've deprecated .pull-right on dropdown menus. To right-align a menu, use `.dropdown-menu-right`. Right-aligned nav components in the navbar use a mixin version of this class to automatically align the menu. To override it, use `.dropdown-menu-left.`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
 ...
</ul>
```

if you use haml

```
  %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right/
      %li
          %a{:href => "http://yoursitelogo.co/"}
             %img{:alt => "Some site", :height => "50", :src => "/assets/image.png"}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you add the class `.justify-content-between` to the item on the left, it should push everything after that to the right.

Comment: `.justify-content-between` only works with Bootstrap 4.